# Rails 4.2: Application error using heroku create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Getting an application error using Heroku create. Work in development. Tried Heroku restart but getting the  same error.

heroku run rake db:migrate gave me this message which i have not seen before.

```
(9.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying NOT NULL) 
   (4.1ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations"  ("version")

  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

Migrating to CreatePosts (20151117140811)

   (2.2ms)  BEGIN

== 20151117140811 CreatePosts: migrating ======================================

-- create_table(:posts)

   (8.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "posts" ("id" serial primary key, "title" character varying, "content" text, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
```

**heroku logs**

```
2015-11-17T21:01:58.922113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T21:02:01.619357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 58664 -e production`
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996752+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996753+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996757+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996743+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996757+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T21:02:04.969978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T21:02:04.982155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T21:02:19.841210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=2daf0895-2f82-4b53-8779-d868927d174d fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T21:07:52.541848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T21:07:54.465372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 34156 -e production`
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963293+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963310+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963311+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963312+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963312+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T21:07:56.601024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T21:07:56.592508+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T21:08:11.237584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T21:08:13.869504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 51681 -e production`
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370873+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370893+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370895+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370897+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370898+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T21:08:17.375973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T21:08:17.362848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T21:08:19.043366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=056b3e11-0204-4a64-aab2-9f33928cce07 fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Neils-MacBook-Pro-2:wiki123 neilpatel$
```

**Gemfile**

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.2.2'


gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg', group: :production


gem 'spring',        group: :development


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.1'
end
```

also updated the spring gem to

```
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.3.0'
end
```

also updated the spring gem as advised in the heroku logs to

gem 'spring', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.3', group: :development

ran heroku open and get the following message

```
2015-11-17T20:52:47.008259+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T20:52:47.356212+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T20:52:47.415652+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a2f4d0a by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T20:52:47.415652+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T20:52:47.721228+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-17T20:52:47.721239+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T20:52:50.084314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 15687 -e production`
2015-11-17T20:52:52.299661+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T20:52:52.299686+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T20:52:52.299703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T20:52:52.299720+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T20:52:52.299736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T20:52:52.299775+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T20:52:53.219221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T20:52:53.217867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T20:52:53.202791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T20:52:55.291203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 37936 -e production`
2015-11-17T20:52:57.066805+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T20:52:57.066819+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T20:52:57.066821+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T20:52:57.066820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T20:52:57.066822+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T20:52:57.066823+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T20:52:57.652025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T20:52:57.644122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T20:53:12.090669+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T20:53:15.086077+00:00 heroku[run.7997]: Awaiting client
2015-11-17T20:53:15.126176+00:00 heroku[run.7997]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-11-17T20:53:15.445357+00:00 heroku[run.7997]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-17T20:53:20.527470+00:00 heroku[run.7997]: Process exited with status 0
2015-11-17T20:53:20.542413+00:00 heroku[run.7997]: State changed from up to complete
2015-11-17T20:54:06.611902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=91c5e397-df18-4ed2-8b38-7a99f0acd7a5 fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T20:54:09.852632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=2aaa7177-4534-48c9-afc9-64e8ff2e8563 fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T20:54:09.986585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=ffe1b818-0924-4989-840c-f9589c3e02c7 fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T20:57:17.611886+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-17T20:57:17.611896+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T20:57:17.479563+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1402961 by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T20:57:17.479619+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T20:57:17.972832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T20:57:20.345858+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 47455 -e production`
2015-11-17T20:57:21.711597+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T20:57:21.711626+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T20:57:21.711627+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T20:57:21.711627+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T20:57:21.711628+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T20:57:21.711628+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T20:57:22.386419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T20:57:22.400171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T20:57:27.636221+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=c82ba8c6-85de-4ac0-b407-0e70a0293016 fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T21:01:58.961493+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T21:01:58.961483+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-17T21:01:58.802834+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T21:01:58.802834+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy f9fc5c0 by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T21:01:58.922113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T21:02:01.619357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 58664 -e production`
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996752+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996753+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996757+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996743+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996757+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T21:02:03.996754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T21:02:04.969978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T21:02:04.982155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T21:02:19.841210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=2daf0895-2f82-4b53-8779-d868927d174d fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T21:07:52.541848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T21:07:54.465372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 34156 -e production`
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963293+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963310+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963311+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963312+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T21:07:55.963312+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T21:07:56.601024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T21:07:56.592508+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T21:08:11.237584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T21:08:13.869504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 51681 -e production`
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370873+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370893+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370895+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370897+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T21:08:16.370898+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T21:08:17.375973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T21:08:17.362848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T21:08:19.043366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=056b3e11-0204-4a64-aab2-9f33928cce07 fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T21:17:26.807218+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d922aba by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T21:17:26.807281+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by neil@myindianweddingapp.com
2015-11-17T21:17:26.909902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T21:17:27.222648+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-17T21:17:27.222657+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T21:17:28.953132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 37736 -e production`
2015-11-17T21:17:31.073507+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
2015-11-17T21:17:31.073522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
2015-11-17T21:17:31.073524+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
2015-11-17T21:17:31.073525+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T21:17:31.073525+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
2015-11-17T21:17:31.073526+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T21:17:32.008445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T21:17:32.018017+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T21:18:35.592839+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=wiki2015.herokuapp.com request_id=097d7d00-533f-4b9a-b588-6cfe369b332e fwd="80.42.198.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Neils-MacBook-Pro-2:wiki123 neilpatel$
```

**heroku run rake console**

```
eils-MacBook-Pro-2:wiki123 neilpatel$ heroku run rails console
Running rails console on wiki2015... up, run.8231
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 65 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `load'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Neils-MacBook-Pro-2:wiki123 neilpatel$
```

Comment: you may want to remove your email address from your log files above.

Comment: What is the output if you run `heroku config:get BUNDLE_WITHOUT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Replace

```
gem 'spring', group: :development
```

by

```
gem 'spring'
```

in your Gemfile.
Then run

```
bundle install
```

to update the Gemfile.lock and commit changes and push the code to heroku. 
It should work.
Because as spring is grouped in development so cannot find this gem but when you remove this group It will be found on production mode.

For more info please look at https://github.com/rails/spring

Comment: This is not a good solution.  From the spring docs: "You must not install Spring on your production environment" https://github.com/rails/spring#deployment

Comment: yeah...this is incorrect. Note that in a brand new rails app generated with `rails new`, the `spring` gem is nested in `group :development`

Comment: Yes.... it is not correct according to the docs but for quick fix I tried it with my project.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to start `rails/server` on Heroku and you don't have `spring` installed on Heroku (which is fine, you don't need it on Heroku), it was throwing an error.

Looks like you don't have `Procfile` set up, or if you do, you're using `rails/server` instead of a production web server.  Heroku [recommends Puma as the webserver](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) you can also use Unicorn.

Follow the instructions in the link above to set up Puma for heroku.  The basic setup is to just create a `Procfile` and a `config/puma.rb` file.

If you're using Puma or Unicorn, you won't be using `rails/server` and so it won't try to load spring.

Comment: yes no procfile has been setup . -> No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker